# Access violation malloc and inheritance C++

Tags: c++, access-violation

I have a GameObject which contains an array of Shapes(assigned via malloc). Shapes have a list of Points in them and can be inherited to be Polygons.
Init code:

```
    GameObject g1(true, true);
    Color c(0, 0, 1, 0);
    Point p(100, 100, 0);
    Polygon s(p, c);
    s.addPoint(p);
    s.createRegularShape(4, 50.0f);
    g1.addShape(s);
```

This is in the header.

```
    Shape* shapes;
```

This is where it breaks (when I try to access the data)

```
void GameObject::draw(unsigned int gameTime)
{
    if(visible)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        shapes[i].draw();//Access violation happens here
    }
}
```

This is how I add the Shape to the Shape array.

```
void GameObject::addShape(Shape const& shape)
{
    if(count == size)
    {
        size += 4;
        shapes = (Shape*)realloc(shapes, sizeof(Shape) * size);
    }
    shapes[count] = shape;
    count++;
}
```

This is where I allocate memory for the Shape. This is called in the constructor when we need to allocate memory to the shapes array.

```
void GameObject::clearShapes(int size)
{
    if(count > 0)
        free(shapes);
    shapes = (Shape*)malloc(sizeof(Shape) * size);
    count = 0;
    GameObject::size = size;
}
```

So basically, what am I doing wrong? How am I getting an access violation from this code? The data seems to all be the correct size and be legitimate.

Comment: Why are you using malloc? This is C++. Use `std::vector<>`. There's no point at all in fixing the code. Throw it away and forget all about malloc. Pretend you'd never heard of it

Answer (score 2):

When you use malloc(), the constructor of the objects is not run. As you can guess this can create all sorts of problems. Use `new` instead.

Do not use malloc() in C++ to create objects.

This:

```
Shape* shapes;
```

is an array of `Shape` objects, *not* an array of `Shape` pointers. That means the initial contents:

```
shapes = (Shape*)malloc(sizeof(Shape) * size);
```

and later:

```
shapes = (Shape*)realloc(shapes, sizeof(Shape) * size);
```

are not constructed. So when you later do:

```
shapes[count] = shape;
```

The assignment operator is called on `shapes[count]`, which is a non-constructed `Shape`. It looks to me like you're waaay into undefined behavior here. Any kind of runtime error is possible.

Get rid of malloc() and realloc(), and instead use an `std::vector<Shape>` where you `push_back()` new Shapes. If you want to keep doing it with a plain dynamic array, then you should switch to an array of pointers instead:

```
Shape** shapes;
```

And only hold `Shape` pointers in there. This of course requires refactoring of your program logic, and I don't see why you would want to keep using malloc() and realloc().

Comment: I'm not using it to create objects. I'm using it to assign memory for an array.

Comment: Use `operator new[]` instead. Or, if you absolutely **must** use `malloc`, you have to use placement `new` to initialize each index of the array before you use it.